# Run various shell commands when NUT reports a low UPS battery

Tags: ups, nut

On a Debian server I've successfully installed the `nut` package so that my Ellipse PRO 1200 UPS's status can be fetched via USB (`upsc my-ups` returns battery level).

Note: I haven't tested what will happens when a power outage occurs yet.

This UPS serves power to other devices than this Debian server: some routers/switches and a NAS.

In this case, considering how I think NUT works, I should install NUT on the NAS and declare it as a NUT slave, this way the Debian server (NUT master) would order the NAS to shutdown when battery are low and then shut itself down.

The problem is that I cannot install NUT on the NAS (OS is not supported), but I can SSH to it an tell it to shutdown.

How/where can I place my own script(s) alongside with what NUT would normally run to order it's slave to shutdown?

The only place I could find is `SHUTDOWNCMD` in */etc/nut/upsmon.conf* file:

```
SHUTDOWNCMD "/sbin/shutdown -h +0"
```

I'm guessing I could replace this command with a hand-made script that would run that SSH-shutdown-command and ends by shutdowning the Debian server too.

Problem is `SHUTDOWNCMD` seems to be meant for last-time actions: when battery is very low. Contacting all the other devices in my own script could take more time than I have before running out of battery.

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

You could try using `upssched.conf(5)` to run your own script on a timer after an event has fired.

A basic `upssched.conf` would be something like this:

```
CMDSCRIPT /bin/your-script.sh
AT ONBATT * EXECUTE emailonbatt
AT ONBATT * START-TIMER upsonbatt 300
AT ONLINE * EXECUTE emailonline
AT ONLINE * CANCEL-TIMER upsonbatt upsonline
```

With this, NUT will:

- Immediately after the UPS goes on battery, run `/bin/your-script.sh emailonbatt`.
- Five minutes after the UPS goes on battery, run `/bin/your-script.sh upsonbatt`.
- Immediately after the UPS regains line power, run `/bin/your-script.sh emailonline`.
- Immediately after the UPS regains line power, also cancel the `upsonbatt` timer if it is still active. Otherwise, run `/bin/your-script.sh upsonline`.

The script could be something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
case $1 in
        emailonbatt)
                  mail -s "UPS on battery power" your@email.com
                  ;;
        emailonline)
                  mail -s "UPS on line power" your@email.com
                  ;;
        upsonbatt)
                  ssh root@nas shutdown -h +0
                  ;;
        upsonline)
                  etherwake 01:23:45:AB:CD:EF
                  ;;
esac
```

The syntax for the AT statement can be found in the man page for `upssched.conf(5)`, and the notify event types available can be found in the man page for `upsmon(8)`.

Answer (score 1):

what you are trying to do (use a pre-established hook) is the most elegant approach.

But when that is not possible because there is no hook or the ones do not suit your needs, a polling approach is also an option.

You could monitor the output of the NUT components at `/var/log` files.

Mine (Salicru UPS on Debian 7), for example logs this:

> Oct 28 13:37:49 hostname upsmon[1766]: UPS salicru@caramon on battery

when the UPS switches to battery, and this

> Oct 28 13:39:39 hostname upsmon[1766]: UPS salicru@caramon on line power

when power is back.

You could simulate a power failure, see the log messages and then write a cron job that runs every minute (or 5 mins), looks for those lines at the logs and takes the action that you want.