# Setup NUT power failure notifications when running computer on UPS battery

Tags: gnome, configuration, notifications, ups, nut

#### Description of the problem

I have [UPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninterruptible_power_supply) [Orvaldi KC2000](http://orvaldi.com/product/9/category/4) (its capacity: 2000VA/1400W) and I want to setup configuration of my [Debian 10](https://www.debian.org/releases/testing/releasenotes) ([Buster](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianBuster) which is currently [testing](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianTesting)) to:

1. *get GUI (preferably GNOME) notifications* when there is power failure and my computer is running on UPS battery (to know that I have little time to save the work and turn off the system),
2. *automatically turn off the computer* when the battery of my UPS is critically low.

I hoped that this is easy with [NUT](http://networkupstools.org/) (*Network UPS Tools*), but it turned out that there is no obvious way to meet the 1-st requirement – which is getting GUI (preferably GNOME) notifications.

#### What I've done to solve the problem?

I've installed [NUT](http://networkupstools.org/) (provided by [`nut`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/nut) package which installs [among others] [`nut-server`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/nut-server) and [`nut-client`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/nut-client)) and I configured it by editing files residing in `/etc/nut` directory.

```
root@host:~# ls /etc/nut
nut.conf  ups.conf  upsd.conf  upsd.users  upsmon.conf  upssched.conf
```

specifically:

- `/etc/nut/upsd.users`:

  ```
  [upsmon]  # name of my UPS
  password = my_UPS_password
  actions = SET
  instcmds = ALL
  upsmon master
  ```
- `/etc/nut/nut.conf`:

  ```
  MODE=standalone
  ```
- `/etc/nut/ups.conf`:

  ```
  maxretry = 3

  [myups]
      driver = blazer_usb
      port = auto
  ```
- `/etc/nut/upsmon.conf`:

  ```
  MONITOR myups@localhost 1 upsmon my_UPS_password master
  MINSUPPLIES 1
  SHUTDOWNCMD "/sbin/shutdown -h +0"
  POLLFREQ 5
  POLLFREQALERT 5
  HOSTSYNC 15
  DEADTIME 15
  POWERDOWNFLAG /etc/killpower
  RBWARNTIME 43200
  NOCOMMWARNTIME 300
  FINALDELAY 5
  ```
- rest of the files (`/etc/nut/upsd.conf`, `/etc/nut/upssched.conf`) have default content – `/etc/nut/upsd.conf` is empty and `/etc/nut/upssched.conf` has single line: `CMDSCRIPT /bin/upssched-cmd`.

(I skipped the comments sections in the above listings.)

After editing above configuration files I needed to run `systemctl restart nut-*`. `*` may be overkill, but I don't remember which services need to be restarted – `nut-client.service`, `nut-driver.service`, `nut-monitor.service` or `nut-server.service`.

I also installed [`nut-monitor`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/nut-monitor) which (quote): *provides nut-monitor, a GUI application to monitor UPS status*. I hoped that [`nut-monitor`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/nut-monitor) has some functionality that allows to popup warning window if UPS battery is low or there is some way to configure GNOME to display status of the UPS, but unfortunately I didn't find any way to do that.

To simulate power failure I use 2 commands: `upsdrvctl -t shutdown` and `upsmon -c fsd` (which shuts down the computer).

Recently [I've found](https://blog.shadypixel.com/monitoring-a-ups-with-nut-on-debian-or-ubuntu-linux/) that there is [`nut-hal-drivers`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/lucid/amd64/nut-hal-drivers) package that provides GUI notifications, but:

1. I can't find this package in Debian repository.
2. [`nut-hal-drivers`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/lucid/amd64/nut-hal-drivers) package apparently doesn't work with `upsmon` and `upsd` provided by the [`nut`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/nut) package.

#### The question

**My question:** how can I setup configuration of my system to popup some kind of warning (preferably popup message native for given desktop environment) if there is power failure and my computer is using UPS' battery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably a partial duplicate of: [Run various shell commands when NUT reports a low UPS battery](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164788/run-various-shell-commands-when-nut-reports-a-low-ups-battery)

The tricky part is to display the notification on the desktop, googling a bit, I found http://rogerprice.org/NUT/ConfigExamples.A5.pdf, page 71 it describes some scripts how to do that.

Comment: [This thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164788/run-various-shell-commands-when-nut-reports-a-low-ups-battery) doesn't address my problem. [The document](http://rogerprice.org/NUT/ConfigExamples.A5.pdf) you linked is *outstanding* and directly refers to the problem. Unfortunately the suggested solution is quite complex, thus I'll wait for more answers for my question. If no one answers, I'll accept your answer. ;-)

Comment: I don't see any easy way of doing that to be honest. I've opened https://github.com/networkupstools/nut/issues/526 to see if some D-Bus API could be created to expose the state of the UPS to other applications. As an interim solution, you could use `upssched` (from the other thread) to write some file on disk and use the content (or the mere presence of that file) to get the state of the UPS. That would requires to write an application that run in the user session as well.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for your [commitment](https://github.com/networkupstools/nut/issues/526)! You definitely deserved +1 and accepted answer tick ✔. Nonetheless I wait for a response from NUT developers.